# Spring "Integrating Data" Getting started guide - using variables in the integration.xml file

Tags: spring-integration, spring-boot

I've worked through the "[Integrating Data](http://spring.io/guides/gs/integration/)" guide on the Spring website and have been trying to determine how to use configuration settings (substitution) in the `integration.xml` file rather than hard code various items. This is primarily driven by a desire to externalise some of the configuration from the XML and take advantage of Spring Boot's ability to allow for externalised configuration.

I've been trying to determine the solution for a while now and thought it's likely to be an easy answer (for those who know how).

In the snippet below (taken from the guide) I've used `${outputDir}` as a placeholder for a configuration item I'll pass into the application:

```
<file:outbound-channel-adapter id="files"
        mode="APPEND"
        charset="UTF-8"
        directory="${outputDir}"
        filename-generator-expression="'HelloWorld'"/>
```

Essentially, I'm trying to determine what I need to do to get the `${outputDir}` substitution working.

As part of working through the problem I reduced the code down to a [demo that I've uploaded to BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/duncan_dickinson/boot-integration-demo/src/d6c714c3226e?at=master):

- `integration.xml` will just copy files from a `file:inbound-channel-adapter` directory to a `file:outbound-channel-adapter`directory
- The `Application` class uses Spring Boot to load the configuration into a DemoIntegration instance and it's the fields in that instance that I'd like to substitute into `integration.xml` at runtime.

Unless I'm mistaken (when I get this to work) I should be able to override the `inputDir` and `outputDir` items in `integration.xml`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `integration.xml` references `${inputDir}`, which is not there.

Just to make it work with the existing config, add/change the `application.properties` file in your classpath with `inputDir=/tmp/in` and `outputDir`.  This way it matches with your used vars in the config file.

If you want to stick with your naming, then change the XML to use `${demo.inputDir}`.  These are the names you are using in your existing `application.properties`.

And if you want to stick to your `@ConfigurationProperties`, then you can put `#{demoConfigration.inputDir}` in the XML to access the bean, where your config is stored.  Note, that your code currently fails (at least for me) as you basically define the bean twice (once per `@EnableConfigurationProperties` and once by `@ComponentScan+@Component` on the config.

Comment: Thank you for this - it solved my problem. I pushed the following fixes: dropped single quotes from the properties file, used ${demo.inputDir} in the integration.xml file, and fixed the redundant @Component items. I can now run `java -jar build/libs/boot-integration-demo-0.1.0.jar --demo.outputDir=/tmp/out --demo.inputDir=/tmp/in` and the default properties are overriden. Thanks!